# Passing Value to EJS File

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, ejs

I am trying to pass a value from a POST route to an EJS file and display it. I have tried redirecting, sending and rendering the results, but it won't get passed to the EJS file.

This is my POST for my login.js:

```
router.post('/', (req, res) => {
  MongoClient.connect(url, { useNewUrlParser: true }, function(err, db) {
  if (err) throw err;
  var dbo = db.db("tmai");
  dbo.collection('users').findOne({username: req.body.user, password: req.body.pass}, function (err, result) {
  if (err) console.log(err);
  if (result === null) res.send('null');
  else {
    res.send({user: result.username});
    // res.redirect('/login');
    // res.render('login/login', {user:req.body.user});
  }
  db.close();
    });
  });
});
```

This is my GET for my homepage where I am trying to get the value to user. After the send request from the POST above, I still get user as undefined:

```
router.get('/', (req, res) => {
  console.log(req);
  res.render('home/home', {user: req.body.user});
});
```

A picture of my folder structure if it helps.

[image: A picture of my folder structure if it helps.]

Comment: Taking the value from `req` object in `res.render('home/home', {user: req.body.user});`, in this case `user` value will only be filled if you passed value of user on request. If you didn't then it will be undefined.

Comment: you might need to use some authentication module such as `passport.js`

Comment: are you sure the user exists? and DB is running?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> This is my GET for my homepage where I am trying to get the value to user. After the send request from the POST above, I still get user as undefined:

Sounds like you need some **sessions**.

Sessions helps your app save/keep user data in mind when the user is currently using your app, example, After login.

After you have verified user information on login you get to store some credentials about that user (username/ID) in session store so it will be accessible on that user's requests, like this.

```js
const express = require('express');
const session = require('express-session');

const app = express();

//- Apply & configure a session middleware
app.use(session({
  secret: 'keyboard cat',
  resave: false,
  saveUninitialized: true
}))

//- Usage in routes
router.post('/', (req, res) => {
  //- Db user lookup code to get result.username
    
  //- Save username in session

  req.session.username = result.username;

  //- Then goes your rendering & redirects code
});
```

From here you will be able to refer to that `username` value we have in a session on other routes the user visits with;

```js
router.get('/', (req, res) => {
  console.log(req.session.username);
  res.render('home/home', {user: req.session.username});
});
```

[Read more on express-sessions](http://expressjs-book.com/index.html%3Fp=128.html)

GitHub: [express-sessions](https://github.com/expressjs/session)